# Skip line doesn't work in Android Studio when I extract string resource?

Tags: android, android-studio, line-breaks

When I extract resources for my textView in Android Studio, the \n (line breaks) turns into a string and incorporates themselves in the actual text. However, if I don't extract string resource and instead keep it hardcoded, the \n's skip a line and work properly.

The XML code (in strings.xml) produces the text below. But won't skip the line.

```
  <string name="tipsBodyOne"> hello \n my name is john</string>
```

[image: Outcome Image]

But if hardcode it, it works fine and skips the line. (But gives me the "Extract String Resource" warning)

[image: hardcoded example]

How could I fix it so that the String Resource gives me the skipped line?

Comment: I recommend that you provide a [mcve] showing what you mean by "extract resources for my textView" and showing exactly what your string resource looks like.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added some images, hope it clarifies it.

Comment: "The XML code (in strings.xml) produces the text below. But won't skip the line." -- it does when I try it, but only when running the app. If you are going by the IDE preview alone, try running the app.